# Can I sink a hot water copper pipe into the ground and keep the heating functionality

Tags: plumbing, heating, hot-water

we are remodeling a our kitchen and the hot water baseboard heating is in the way. We had two ideas. 
1. we let the baseboard heating run under the cabinets
2. we cut open the floor and drop the copper pipe in, covering it up with a metal grille.

Regarding the 2nd Option, will it still heat up the room as it used to before?
Thanks for your Feedback.

Comment: I did option 1 years ago. Since heating cabinets is undesirable, I removed the fins from the section of pipe under the cabinets and wrapped it with pipe insulation.

Answer (score 3):

The hot water baseboard heating will be heating the room mostly due to radiative surfaces that conduct the heat out of the water pipe and into the air of the room. For this to work there needs to be allowance for the air in the room to naturally move from the heater area and into the room.

If you cover it up it will not be heating the room in the same way.

If you end up having to bypass the hot water piping beyond the area where you are now placing cabinets you will have to arrange for alternate radiative devices to be installed elsewhere in the room so that the heating can be effective.

Answer (score 0):

With certain detail changes, option 1 can work - you need to provide for airflow below and behind the cabinets - most base cabinets have 3-4 inches of wasted toe-kick space (kudos to the clever ones with toe-kick drawers instead, but those would be a hindrance in this case) and some space between the cabinets and the wall. By making sure of the space behind, and providing ventilation openings in the toe kick and either the countertop, or (less potential for messy spills) behind the backsplash (moving the backspash forward a few inches and placing a grille on top of it) you could maintain airflow to and from the heater.